# make pyspark code with loops and actions more efficient

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframes df, remain_df.  their schemas are described below.  I am trying to create 3 lists based off these dataframes.  The ultimate goal is to pass these 3 lists, (quantities, weights, utilities) to an optimization model.  so they have to be ultimately in a list type.  I'm using a series of forloops and collect to accomplish this.  the current code is a little slow, and basically just python.  I'm wondering if there isn't a faster more pyspark way to accomplish this.  for example, is there a way to avoid running the collect in the forloops since it means it has to run an action every time?  any tips are greatly appreciated.

dataframes:

```
print(df.schema)

StructType([StructField('producttype', StringType(), True), StructField('storeid', IntegerType(), True), StructField('dateclosed', DateType(), True), StructField('qty', DoubleType(), True), StructField('product_id', StringType(), True), StructField('cost', DoubleType(), True), StructField('netsales', DoubleType(), True)])

print(remain_df.schema)

StructType([StructField('dates', DateType(), True), StructField('product_id', StringType(), True), StructField('daily_product_remaining', DecimalType(28,6), True), StructField('days_out_of_stock', IntegerType(), True), StructField('new_stock', DecimalType(26,6), True), StructField('year', IntegerType(), True), StructField('storeid', IntegerType(), True), StructField('datalake_date', StringType(), True)])
```

code:

```
prdDct = {}
for i in products:
    demand_rows = available.filter(col('product_id') == i).select('demand').collect()
    if demand_rows:
        demand = demand_rows[0][0]
    else:
        demand = 0
        
    base_cost = product_cost.filter(col('product_id') == i).select('base_cost').collect()[0][0]
    base_sales = product_sales.filter(col('product_id') == i).select('base_sales').collect()[0][0]
    prdDct[i] = [[1] * int(demand), base_cost, base_sales]

# Create weights and utilities
weights = []
utilities = []
product_values = list(prdDct.values())
for j in range(len(product_values)):
    if j == 0:
        weights = [product_values[j][1] * x for x in range(len(product_values[j][0]) + 1)]
        utilities = [product_values[j][2] * x for x in range(len(product_values[j][0]) + 1)]
    else:
        weights += [product_values[j][1] * x for x in range(len(product_values[j][0]) + 1)]
        utilities += [product_values[j][2] * x for x in range(len(product_values[j][0]) + 1)]

# Create quantities matrix
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType

# Create quantities matrix
quantities_list = []
product_values = list(prdDct.values())

for j in range(len(product_values)):
    if j == 0:
        row = list(range(len(product_values[j][0]) + 1)) + [0] * (len(weights) - (len(product_values[j][0]) + 1))
        rlngth = len(list(range(len(product_values[j][0]) + 1)))
    else:
        row = [0] * rlngth + list(range(len(product_values[j][0]) + 1))
        rlngth += len(list(range(len(product_values[j][0]) + 1)))
        row += [0] * (len(weights) - rlngth)
    
    quantities_list.append(row)



reshaped_quantities=np.array(quantities_list).T.tolist()
```